# Set the bgcolor attribute value

Tags: javascript, flash

The following doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<title>Test</title>
<embed id="foo" src="http://www.w3schools.com/media/bookmark.swf" width="400" height="40" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("foo").setAttribute("bgcolor", "#00FF00");
</script>
```

But if you change *setAttribute* to *("width", "800")*, it works with no problem! What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("foo")
                         .setAttribute("style", "background-color: #00FF00;");
```

`width` is an attribute.    `background-color` is a style and should be placed as such

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but they are two different things. To see what I mean please try adding bgcolor="#00FF00" to the embed code and compare it with changing the style background color.

Answer (score 2):

According [to the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#the-embed-element) `embed` has a `width` attribute but doesn't have a `bgcolor` attribute.

It is a replaced element anyway, so whatever colour it is, it will take from the Flash object anyway.

Comment: Then how can I change an attribute value without using setAttribute method? Any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Like Nael said `background-color` is a style.  That said beyond the fact that updating  the existing style attribute using setAttribute is very difficult, it's also [not very reliable](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/setAttribute).  If your planning on doing anything more involved seriously consider a JavaScript library.

Comment: Is there an alternative to setAttribute method?

Comment: Yeah for sure, use the [YUI DOM package](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/dom), it's pretty small and gives you an extensive API for manipulating DOM elements.  Take a look at the Examples on the above link.  You'll see examples of using addClass.

Comment: I saw the reference and learned how to add class, etc. But I could find nothing related to adding/changing an attribute.

Comment: @Rain - Sorry I thought you only wanted to change the style attribute.  If you want to change other attributes, use [YUI Element](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/element).  YUI Element extends YUI DOM, so basically you can do `var el = new YAHOO.util.Element('foo')` and then simply do `el.set('id','myid1')` to change an attribute.  With YUI Element you can also do `el.addClass('myclass')` (that's because YUI Element extends DOM)