# Using getElementById() with bgcolor attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Why this code doesn't work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Home </title>
    </head>

    <body id = "b" bgcolor = "lightblue">

        <button onclick = "document.getElementById('b').bgcolor = 'lightgreen'"> Light Green </button>

    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to change text attribute value in the body tag and it works, but for some reason it doesn't work with the bgcolor and the background still has the lightblue color.

Comment: Why you are using deprecated attributes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set the bgcolor attribute value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792044/set-the-bgcolor-attribute-value)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The style is set via `.style.backgroundColor` (see MDN for details on the [`style` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)). `bgcolor` as an attribute has been obsolete for well over a decade, and the reflected property was `bgColor` (case is significant).

So:

```
document.getElementById("b").style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
```

---

Generally, though, mixing presentation with markup isn't ideal. Instead, consider adding/removing a class that you style with CSS, e.g.:

```
document.getElementById("b").classList.add('clicked');
```

...with

```
.clicked {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

...in your stylesheet.

(`classList` is well-supported in modern browsers, and there's a polyfill for obsolete browsers; more [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).)